# Best way to repeat a process and continue even if it fails

Tags: c#, asp.net, process, task, database-restore

I have a program that restores databases. Basically the program reads from a file and restores one database at a time. The program runs 1 time per database. I need a way to repeat this until all databases are restored. Even if the database restore isn't successful, i need the process to repeat until all databases are attempted to be restored. I am thinking of having another program call the program I just mentioned. So something like this:

```
    public const string databaseAttemptedRestore = "C:\\Logs\\AttemptedDatabaseRestore.log";
    public const string databasesToRestore = "C:\\Logs\\DatabasesToRestore.log";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        //Repeats restore, reading from databasesToRestore. Needs to be called by task scheduler
        Action toRepeat = () =>
        {
            var proc = new Process();

          //database restore program
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Projects\DbRestoreProdConsole\bin\Debug\DbRestoreProdConsole.exe";

            // set up output redirection

            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

            proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Windows\SysWOW64";

            // see below for output handler

            proc.Start();
            proc.WaitForExit();
        };
        double lineCount = File.ReadLines(databasesToRestore).Count();
        double repeat = Math.Ceiling(lineCount / 2);
        Enumerable.Range(0, (int)repeat).ToList().ForEach(i => toRepeat());


    }
}
```

}

I am trying to figure out the best solution to this repeating process where I can track errors and run the program smooth etc. The program runs after hours so it doesn't need to be a fast running program. The most databases I will restore per night is around 8. but it usually will be 1 or 2 per night. Any suggestions is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: where are you actually tracking and or handling errors? what you have written is basic assumption that your program will always run without any errors..  does the toRepeat Action currently work.. or only for 1 file..?

Comment: I use log4net to track errors. Yeah, this works if program runs with no errors. But this is just a basic idea of what I want to do. I am completely open to suggestions as I have not deployed this yet. I know the way I am currently doing this is not the best by far.

Comment: Also it's 1 file with a list of databases. The repeat just repeats the processes depending on how many listed databases there are